# Funcionamiento de Map.set() y sumar el numero de veces que se repite una clave como valor

Tags: javascript, map, set, prompt

tengo que crear un mapa que contenga una palabra recibida a través de prompt como clave y el numero de veces que se repite la misma palabra como valor. Tengo que crear un prompt que se repita hasta que se cancele o se deje vacio, Mientras tanto irá guardando cada palabra.
Este ha sido mi intento pero no logro dar con el resultado correcto. Ya que estoy un poco mareada con el funcionamiento de map y sobre como funciona a la hora de guardar palabras y extraerlas correctamente.

Este es mi codigo, agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda.

```js
function mapa() {
  let contar = 1;
  while (true) {
    let pregunta = window.prompt('Escribe palabras');
    if (pregunta == null || pregunta.trim() === '') {
      break;
    } else {
      agregarMapa();
    }
  }
  
  function agregarMapa(pregunta, contar) {
    var map = new Map();
    map.set(pregunta, contar++);
    console.log(map);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola @azucarilla, corrigeme si estoy mal, lo que entiendo es que quieres que el usuario ingrese palabras y se cuenten si se repiten utilizando [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) ¿verdad?

Comment: si, exactmente eso :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta lo que aclaraste en el comentario lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera y te explico algunos errores que estabas cometiendo:

En tu función:

```
function agregarMapa(pregunta, contar) {
  var map = new Map();
  map.set(pregunta, contar++);
  console.log(map);
}
```

Estabas siempre creando un nuevo `Map` por lo que no estabas persistiendo las palabras en el arreglo y los valores adecuados de sus respectivos contadores.

También cuando invocabas la función que se debería ocupar de almacenar la palabra y el respectivo valor del contador; no estabas pasandole ningún argumento:

```
if (pregunta == null || pregunta.trim() === '') {
  break;
} else {
  agregarMapa();
}
```

```js
function mapearPalabras() {
  // El primer problema anterior mencionado se resuelve definiendo el mapa 
  // en el cuerpo de tu función principal para que preserve su estado y valores
  let mapaDePalabras = new Map();

  function agregarPalabrasAlMapa(palabra) {
    // Definimos nuestro contador localmente donde realmente lo necesitamos
    let contador = 1;

    // Utilizamos el método `get` de nuestro objeto `mapaDePalabras`
    // para comprobar si existe un valor con la entrada `palabra`
    // si existe nos devolverá un `1` porque es el valor de nuestro contador
    // inicial, si no existe nos devolverá `undefined` por lo que
    // podremos evaluar esta variable como booleana
    const palabraYaExiste = mapaDePalabras.get(palabra);
    
    // Con la variable anterior explicada podemos disminuir
    // enormemente nuestra complejidad ciclomatica
    if (palabraYaExiste) {
      contador = palabraYaExiste + 1;
      mapaDePalabras.set(palabra, contador);
    }
    
    mapaDePalabras.set(palabra, contador);
    console.log(`La palabra ${palabra} se ha ingresado ${contador} veces`);
  }

  while (true) {
    let palabra = window.prompt('Escribe palabras');
    if (!palabra) {
      break;
    }

    // Le pasamos su respectivo argumento
    agregarPalabrasAlMapa(palabra);
  }
}

// Invocamos nuestra función principal para probar que todo funcione
mapearPalabras();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, lo he entendido a la perfección, tu respuesta ha sido totalmente clara y ordenada gracias!!!

Comment: @azucarilla Me alegra haber podido ayudarte!